# XML to Dictionary/Dataframe

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I'm learning python at the moment and I've had success with using CSV's together with Pandas dataframes but I'm now trying to use XML, however I'm not figuring out how 'select' data from elements in my XML.

My XML file looks like this:

```xml
<DATABASE>
    <OBJECT>
        <PROPERTY NAME="__type" VALUE=".com.infoblox.dns.bind_a"/>
        <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="192.168.10.1"/>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <PROPERTY NAME="__type" VALUE=".com.infoblox.dns.bind_a"/>
        <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="192.168.20.1"/>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <PROPERTY NAME="__type" VALUE=".com.infoblox.dns.bind_ptr"/>
        <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="1.20.168.192.in-addr.arpa"/>
    </OBJECT>
</DATABASE>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to search my root for PROPERTY elements with NAME __type and VALUE .com.infoblox.dns.bind_a, when I find a OBJECT ELEMENT that contains this NAME and VALUE I want to save some other NAME/VALUE pairs in a dictionary.

My end goal is a dictionary looking like:
{'__type' : ['.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a','.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a'], 'address' : ['192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1']}

This was achieved using the following code but also includes the .com.infoblox.dns.bind_ptr __type, now I was wondering if anyone can help me with the logic needed to only iterate through PROPERTY elements if the attribute __type == .com.infoblox.dns.bind_a and then if that is the case only put all property name/value pairs under that object in the dictionary.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from  collections import defaultdict

xml_data = open('onedb.xml').read()
root = et.XML(xml_data)
dict = defaultdict(list)

for child in root:
    for newchild in child:
        property = newchild.get('NAME')
        value = newchild.get('VALUE')
        dict[property].append(value)
```

So my resulting dictionary now =

```
print(dict)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'__type': ['.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a', '.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a', '.com.infoblox.dns.bind_ptr'], 'address': ['192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1', '1.20.168.192.in-addr.arpa']})
```

And I want it to look like:

```
{'__type' : ['.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a','.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a'], 'address' : ['192.168.10.1', '192.168.20.1']}
```

The end result will be to put the data in a dataframe from pandas

Answer (score 0):

If the first element of `OBJECT` element inside your XML file is always `__type`, then you can add few lines to your code to achieve your goal.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
from  collections import defaultdict

xml_data = open('onedb.xml').read()
root = et.XML(xml_data)
dict_ = defaultdict(list)

for child in root:
    for i, newchild in enumerate(child):
        property_ = newchild.get('NAME')
        value = newchild.get('VALUE')
        if i == 0 and property_ == '__type' and not value == '.com.infoblox.dns.bind_a':
            break
        dict_[property_].append(value)
```

I do not think it is the most pythonic solution, but it works. What I did? I just added `child` iterator into `enumerate` function that returns `(index of item, item)` tuple. It means I can find out, which item from the iterator is the first one. Then I just check, if the first item is `__type` and is equal to your desired value. If not, I tell the program to stop the iteration within `for` cycle with `break` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

xml = '''<DATABASE>
    <OBJECT>
        <PROPERTY NAME="__type" VALUE=".com.infoblox.dns.bind_a"/>
        <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="192.168.10.1"/>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <PROPERTY NAME="__type" VALUE=".com.infoblox.dns.bind_a"/>
        <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="192.168.20.1"/>
    </OBJECT>
    <OBJECT>
        <PROPERTY NAME="__type" VALUE=".com.infoblox.dns.bind_ptr"/>
        <PROPERTY NAME="address" VALUE="1.20.168.192.in-addr.arpa"/>
    </OBJECT>
</DATABASE>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for obj in root.findall('.//OBJECT'):
    for p in obj.findall('.//PROPERTY'):
        data[p.attrib['NAME']].append(p.attrib['VALUE'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head())
```

output

```
                        __type                    address
0    .com.infoblox.dns.bind_a               192.168.10.1
1    .com.infoblox.dns.bind_a               192.168.20.1
2  .com.infoblox.dns.bind_ptr  1.20.168.192.in-addr.arpa
```